# Php Update Text From Text File Everyday

Tags: php, html

Ok so I am trying to make a text appear so something like this

`<h1>Text Goes here</h1>`

but I wanted that text to be in a text file which would update everyday from a text file which would already have all the text so for example 365 lines of text and this would be using php I have tried it before but I couldnt make it work.
Code :

`$lines = file("quotes.txt");
$day = date("z");
echo $lines[$day];`

Comment: I have tried this many many times?

Comment: Have you checked the content of your two variables ```$lines``` and ```$day```?

Comment: @MatthiasW. Im not really good at php I got this code from someone on Stack I posted this cause i needed help! And I have checked

Comment: Then I don't see why it shouldn't work if your data is correct. ```<?php
$lines = array( 29 => "boo", 30 => "hi", 31 => "hello" );
$day = date("z");
echo "day: ", $day, ", line: ", $lines[$day];
?>``` works for me.

Comment: I need it so the text is stored in a file and using php it takes a the first line of text and uses it on the first day second day it uses second line etc. @MatthiasW.

Answer (score 1):

If your file contains plain text you will need to convert it to an array before you can get the line you're after. Try this...

```
$text = file("quotes.txt");

$search = array ("\r\n", "\r");
$text = str_replace($search, "\n", $text);

$array = explode("\n", $text);

$line = date("z");

echo $array[$line];
```

Also, don't forget it's a leap year this year, you'll need 366 lines of text!

Comment: but where is the html I would use ?

Comment: Before you get into the HTML, does the code return what you're expecting to see?

Comment: Im sorry I was gone umm I tried what u gave me but i couldnt make it echo i made the text file and everything